# Idk whats wrong C# socket read problems

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

ok so iv made a sort of remote command operator. it is made of 2 sections the server and the client the client sends a command the server executes it and returns the output.

now for some resone i cant read all of the output i can only read a few lines then it just waits for the time out.

i send the output of the command like so
"[CommandName:PID]:OneLineOfOutput\n"
and then this repeats for each line that the command outputed

and then i try to read this line by line and when there isnt something to read i time out the reading process and wait for a new command to send to the server.

the kind of stuff its ment to output looks like this

```
[ListCmds:1232]:ListCmds:0
[ListCmds:1232]:Shutdown:1
[ListCmds:1232]:FullSysShutdown:2
[ListCmds:1232]:Restart:3
```

and this is what i see on the console

```
[ListCmds:1232]:ListCmds:0
[ListCmds:1232]:Shutdown:1
```

it just seems to skip 2 lines.

my reading thread code

```
private static void ReturnManager(Socket Soc)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(100);
        using (StreamReader RS = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(Soc)))
        {
            DateTime TMR = DateTime.Now;
            while (true)
            {
                if (RS.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(RS.ReadLine());
                    TMR = DateTime.Now;
                }
                if (!Soc.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (DateTime.Now - TMR > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LastReadTimeoutSeconds))
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
        Soc.Close();
        Soc.Dispose();
    }
```

now before you ask i did make sure all the data was beeing sent throu the socket on the serer side its just not beeing fully read by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void ReturnManager(Socket Soc)
    {

        //Thread.Sleep(100);
        using (StreamReader RS = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(Soc)))
        {
            DateTime TMR = DateTime.Now;
            while (true)
            {
                while (RS.Peek() > 0 | Soc.Available > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(RS.ReadLine());
                    TMR = DateTime.Now;
                }
                if(DateTime.Now - TMR > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LastReadTimeoutSeconds))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!Soc.Connected) break;
                        else
                        {
                            Soc.Send(new byte[1] { 255 });//Verify that the Server is still keeping the Socket open thus the command is still active
                            TMR = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Soc.Close();
        Soc.Dispose();
    }
```

i got it to work like this it will now read all the data untill the socket closes or stops accepting incomming packets.